# How to calculate sum of the integers from $m$ to $n$.

Tags: summation

How to calculate the sum of the integers from $m$ to $n$?

Is this correct?
$$ \frac{n (n+1)}{2} - \frac{m (m+1)}{2}$$

Comment: I don't know.  Did you test it?  Did you have a reason for thinking it was true.  Was the reason a good one?

Comment: Try average of end numbers multiplied by difference of end numbers "repaired " if you will.. $ \dfrac{n+m}{2}\cdot (n-m+1) $

Comment: @fleablood:  I though it was right nut failed my test case that why i ask here  to save time

Comment: What I was hinting at is Sum to n - Sum to (m-1) =Sum m to n.  And as Sum to k is $\frac {k (k+1)}2$ then Sum m to n must be $\frac {n (n+1)}2-\frac {(m-1)m}2$.

Comment: Now i understand , thank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $m\le n$, you are rather subtracting the sum from $0$ to $m-1$ to the sum from $0$ to $n$, so $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-\frac{m(m-1)}{2}=\frac{(m-n+1)(m+n)}2$. This "incidentally" works when $m<0$ or $n\le0$ as well.

Comment: The result of the subtraction should be (n-m+1)(m+n)/2 if you assume m is less than or equal to n, isn't it?

Comment: As the previous comment suggested, it should be $n-m$ instead of $m-n$.

Answer (score 5):

This is a special of the sum of consecutive terms of an arithmetic progression $(a_n)$: such a sum  is equal to the `arithmetic mean  of the first and the last terms`, multiplied by the `number of terms`:
$$a_m+a_{m+1}+\dots+a_n=\frac{a_m+a_n}2(n-m+1).$$
In the present case, you obtain
$$m+(m+1)+\dots+n=\frac{m+n}2 (n-m+1).$$

Answer (score 1):

Your error was an indexing one.

$\frac {n (n+1)}2-\frac {m (m+1)}2 =(1+2+...+n)-(1+2+3+....+m)=(m+1)+...+n$  which is shifted from what you actually want.

You want:

$m+...+n=(1+.....+n)-(1+... (m-1))=\frac {n (n+1)}2-\frac {(m-1)m}2$.